# Compiler skipping over loop

Tags: c, flops

I am compiling flops via a loop with simple operations like such:

```
for (i = beginvar; i < endvar; i++) {
    for (j = beginvar; j < endvar; j++) {   
        num1 = ((num1 + num2) / num1);
    }
}
```

I never do anything with num1, however, and so the compiler is skipping over it and this loop takes 0 ms no matter how large beginvar and endvar are.

My question is, how can I force the compiler to execute the nested loop?

I've tried declaring num1 as volatile, but this does fewer optimizations than I want. I want the compiler to optimize, but I want it to execute this loop as well.

I also would not like to print anything to the terminal

Comment: You should turn off optimization and use your `num` variable in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the value of `num1` after the loop for something, so that the compiler cannot trivially eliminate it.

Comment: What can I do with it? doing num1++ after the loop gives me a floating point exception, im not sure why. It works when I print it to the terminal, but I don't want to print it.

Comment: You can print it to the console, for instance.